# Api calling error while parsing the data to model class in dio flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart, parsing, dio

Error:

E/flutter (28049): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:object_mapper/src/mappable.dart': Failed assertion: line 8 pos 12: 'constructor != null': RegistrationResponse is not defined in Reflection.factories
E/flutter (28049): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:51:61)
E/flutter (28049): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:5)
E/flutter (28049): #2      new Mappable (package:object_mapper/src/mappable.dart:8:12)
E/flutter (28049): #3      Mapper.toObject (package:object_mapper/src/mapper.dart:22:20)
E/flutter (28049): #4      DioClient.userRegistration (package:chavara/src/features/registration/service/registration_service.dart:20:45)
E/flutter (28049): 
E/flutter (28049):
I/ViewRootImpl@219a9d3MainActivity: ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@219a9d3MainActivity: ViewPostIme pointer 1

code:

```
    RegistrationResponse? user;

    try {
      Response userData =await WebUtil.createDio().post('/User',
      data:requestData);
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('User Info: ${userData.data}');
      }
      user = Mapper.fromJson(userData.data).toObject<RegistrationResponse>();
    } on DioError catch (e) { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Mappable.factories = {
      RegistrationResponse: () => RegistrationResponse(),
      Relation: () => Relation()
    };

After adding this code in class, the code is working fine...
```

Answer (score 0):

List users =
userData.map((userData.data) => Mapper.fromJson(data)).toList();

Comment: This is not working...@Amit Jajoo

Comment: @kapiltk you can write user = RegistrationResponse.fromJson(userData.data);